# if else condition true it will run until it doesn't false, but when else condition is true it will run continuously until when it false

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have If - else condition,

```
High = [18365.5, 18979.25, 19297.4, 19874.8, 20288.0, 20504.65, 20398.2] 

Low = [17855.5, 18265.0, 18822.55, 18742.15, 19492.55, 20055.55, 20131.25] 

Close = [18317.05, 18969.95, 18857.6, 19804.0, 20260.15, 20285.0, 20215.7]

length = len(Close) - 1

i = 0
a = 1
Trend = ["No Trend"]
Difference = ["No Trend"]
while i<length:
    if Close[a] > Low[i]:
        trend = "Long"
        Trend.append(trend)
        difference = Close[a] - Low[i]
        Difference.append(difference)
    elif Close[a] < High[i]:
        trend = "Short"
        Trend.append(trend)
        difference = Close[a] - High[i]
        Difference.append(difference)
    i = i + 1
    a = a + 1
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(High, Low, Close, Difference, Trend, From_date, End_date)),
               columns =['High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Difference', 'Trend', 'From_date', 'End_date'])
display(df)
```

So i want if `Close[a] > Low[i]` condition is true so it will run continuously until it doesn't false, and when if condition will false so else `Close[a] < High[i]` condition start, so it will run continuously unitll it will not false.

I am showing you the below data frame, which will give you a clear-cut idea.
[image]

In this Dataframe there are three columns which are High, Low, Close, and the rest of the columns are made by these three column.

So in if - condition is true so it's print "Long" continuously until It doesn't false, but when else condition start so else condition should run, and start checking this condition `Close[a] < High[i]`. until it doesn't false.

I'm trying my best to explain my question
And Sorry, if my explanation is not good.

Comment: Perhaps I am mistaken here, but why don't you use a for loop since the length of the data is known?

Comment: Dataframe is the out put, of this code.

Comment: But I can say in the picture, where short comes, after next row there should be one more short come, cause if one-time short hit then it should start to check Close < High condition.